# how to create a custom user group in AEM using APIs

Tags: security, aem

I am looking to solve a use case that needs me to create a custom user group using any API available within AEM 6.1.
Beyond this, i also want to add specific permissions onto the custom group.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Hemant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UserManager](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/UserManager.html) - createGroup() to create the groups and for permissions you might have to use.

```
javax.jcr.security.AccessControlManager
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.JackrabbitAccessControlList
javax.jcr.security.Privilege
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of AuthorizableServlet to create usergroups and users. Take a look at this link below.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/security/user/servlets/AuthorizableServlet.html

You can follow this up by making use of accessmanager api's to impose permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this, does this work for AEM 6.1 too?

Comment: This has been deprecated in 6.1.